# KDE Plasma over VNC on Ubuntu in Chroot on Android using Linux Deploy

Tags: ubuntu, vnc, kubuntu, plasma5, tightvnc

As you can see form the title, I am running a weird setup.

I am using Linux Deploy on my Android 11 to host an Ubuntu instance in a chroot environment, so that I can run full-fat Linux applications on my phone without loosing Android.

To connect to the Linux GUI I am using vnc (server is xtightvnc, client is RealVNC VNC viewer).

Since Linux Deploy is not really maintained any more and a bit outdated, it only lets me install Ubuntu 18.04 with LXDE, and not Kubuntu directly. I updated to Ubuntu 20.04 and installed `kubuntu-desktop` using `tasksel`. I also selected `sddm` as Display Manager.

This changed nothing when connecting using VNC, it still launches LXDE.

The command line that Linux Deploy uses to start the vnc server looks like this:

```
Xtightvnc :0 -desktop X -auth /home/android/.Xauthority -geometry 1080x2000
             -depth 16 -rfbwait 120000 -rfbauth /home/android/.vnc/passwd -rfbport 5900
             -fp /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc/,/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1/,/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/,/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/
             -co /etc/X11/rgb -dpi 200
```

`.xinitrc` looks like this:

```
XAUTHORITY=$HOME/.Xauthority
export XAUTHORITY
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG
echo $$ > /tmp/xsession.pid
. $HOME/.xsession
```

`.xsession` contains

```
exec startlxde
```

So I figured, that directly starts lxde, no matter what else I configured. So instead, I changed to

```
exec startplasma-x11
```

Which gives me a grey screen and nothing else.

So I tried

```
exec /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc
```

With the same result.

The last thing I came up with, was this:

```
unset SESSION_MANAGER
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS

export XKB_DEFAULT_RULES=base
export QT_XKB_CONFIG_ROOT=/usr/share/X11/xkb
kstart5 plasmashell &
dbus-launch startplasma-x11
```

The result is a grey screen, and once ever few tries, a window that tells me, that `kwin_x11` crashed.

What do I need to change to get KDE Plasma over VNC in this setup?

Edit: I piped the stdout of `dbus-launch startplasma-x11` into a file and put it into a pastebin here: https://pastebin.com/nnrZY82x

It's mostly complete, but I removed some duplicate lines, since some lines occurred a few hundred times.